# Why I get "the server responded with a status of 404 " for remixicon.woff2 with reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, icons, remix.run

I'm using remixicon for displaying icons in the menu which are stored in MySQL database in my reactJs application. But I always get : the server responded with a status of 404  for emixicon.woff2 despite I already imported it.
this is the code :

```
    <Icon name={item.menu_icon} type={item.menu_icon_type} />
            {
              item.menu_icon == '' && item.menu_icon_type == '' &&
              <>
                <Icon name='home-3' type='line' />

              </>
            }
```

This is how I imported it :

```
import Icon from 'react-remixicon'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen on .NET server because it doesn't handle woff2 file types by default. You can include this in web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

inside the section of:

```
<system.webServer>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: No I'm using laravel and reactJS